# I can't echo acf textarea in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, advanced-custom-fields

I could extract text field, select field, and “textarea” field with 1 row

But when “textarea” field have 2 rows and more, it’s failed in this js script:

```
var product_advantage = "<?php echo the_field('product_advantage', 'user_1') ?>";
alert(product_advantage);
```

I tested with do-shortcode functions, "echo get_field", "the field", it's failed too.
Something wrong with 2 rows or more of textarea.

Comment: use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly right. Template literals with `` syntax solve multi line. You save my life!